# User Login message box when opening blender to choose a different startup file on the start

Tags: python, interface

I'm wondering how can I make a messagebox with the fields username and password to appear when blender is opened, and depending on the user's credentials a different startup file will start. I'm thinking that this can be done where the credentials will be staticly saved within a python script which will run when launching blender like:

```
if username == 'user1' and password == 'user1pass':
 open starup file1
elif username is 'user2' and password is 'user2pass':
 open starup file2
else:
 display a message saying "sorry not a correct user" and make the user try loginning again
```

Any thoughts please how this can be done?

Comment: What are you expecting to get as an answer? This is a very complicated subject and, furthermore, there are many ways to do it. The pseudocode that you posted is not really showing that you tried anything.

Comment: @pycoder I didn't post what I tried because I don't know from where I should start or how this can be done.

Comment: @pycoder  maybe he have no idea how to ask, because he have no enough knowledge about this. In my opinion this is not bad idea - If this allow choose different User preferences (including sets of add-ons) for different kind of work and different Startup File on start, in best case from Splash screen. I thing this can be useful. Only I'm not sure whether it is worth the effort.

Comment: @Shubol3D thank you very much. The reason my question wasn't detailed enough because as you mentioned I just have no enough knowledge how this can be done. And yes, I want to choose a different startup file on the start.

Comment: So you are basically asking, "How can I add custom properties and operators to the splash screen?"

Comment: Look at where [blender finds the startup file](https://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html) and make a script that authenticates and moves the relevant files into place before starting blender. Note that the first location is local to the blender binary, this allows you to install multiple copies of blender with different versions/addons/startup files installed that can each be run separately.

Comment: @sambler thank you very much for your comment. Is it possible to show or advise me how this can be done please? as I'm not familiar with this area at all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have the location of the startup that blender will use and a location that stores the presets you want to use. [Copy the preset files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/123198/2684771) into place based on whatever criteria, like your example but you copy the file into place not open it, then start blender. Depending on your system you could use python, shell or batch scripts to do it, as copying files around is not blender related it is better asked at [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) for help getting it to work.

Comment: @sambler but this means that the user will have to run a shell or batch script before opening blender and I want to avoid this, what I want is a different presets depending on the user clicking and opening blender without the need of clicking on something else (batch script,...) before opening blender. Any thoughts?

Comment: You have the user run the script instead of blender. You can rename the blender binary and have the script run the renamed binary so the user doesn't know any different. I actually have [this script](http://pasteall.org/86495/bash) in `~/bin/blender` with `~/bin` as the first folder in my PATH.

Comment: @sambler thanks for the clarification, that makes sense, running a script which asks for username and password and depending on them one of two startup files will be copied to the startup location and then open blender. I'm honestly not familiar with the blender binary and didn't understand the script you sent (I apologize for my ignorance), is it possible to show me a documented script doing what I need please? I'm running on windows. I'd be very thankful for your assistance.

Comment: To do it using python [this script](http://pasteall.org/86501/python) is a rough **UN-TESTED** start but should give an idea where to start. I don't use windows so won't attempt a bat file for you.

Comment: @sambler thank you very much. Any idea how to make the user enter username and password? so that depending on what he enters it will be compared with the username and password in the if conditions.

Comment: [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) is usually included with standard python installs, otherwise you can require the users to install gtk or qt to use your setup.

Comment: Also... why do you want to ask for a password? Controlling which startup file loads will not create any kind of security. It would be more likely used to select different between configurations of blender when starting a new project. If you wish to create security, you should use some scripts to create different user accounts on the windows machine instead.

Answer (score 1):

This question is too open-ended to be answered in detail, so I'll answer generally. Before we talk about how to create such a solution, there are some issues with what you are trying to do.

First, there is no "security" offered by what you are doing, so there is no reason to ask for a password. You can simply let the user choose from a list of startup profiles. If you wish to provide some kind of security, you need to use your operating system's user accounts. You said you are using windows, so you would want to create a separate windows account for each user.

Second, it's strange to be asking for "username", since the startup file is only a set of presets for new projects. If the user saves his work, and loads it later, loading the file will overwrite the startup file information. Choosing a different startup file would more likely be used to choose different "configurations" of blender, for different types of tasks.

Therefore, the only sensible way to use the UI you are suggesting is actually to present a list of "startup configurations" and let the user pick between them. The following will explain one way you might do that.

You will need to create some custom UI for your startup-selector using python. I don't believe you can modify the splash screen from python, so I would do this by making a custom page in the user-preferences UI. This custom page will contain your UI and the logic to load the proper startup file. (See `scripts/startup/bl_ui/space_userpref.py`)

Once you have your custom UI for picking a startup file and loading it, you can make a startup file which loads this when blender starts. Configure blender the way you want, with only one view on the screen, showing the user-pref space, with your custom space-chooser showing. Then do File->Save Startup File. Now this will show every time blender is launched.

That should give you a startup-file selector on launch.